# object property nil despite assigning him value

Tags: swift, properties

I have the following class:

```
class Event: NSObject {


    var eventID :String!
    var name: String!
init(name: String,eventID: String) {

        self.eventID = eventID
        self.name = name
    }
```

Here in my View Im using an instance of my class

```
     var selectedEvent: Event?

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

                let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

                print(listOfEvents[indexPath.row].eventID) // print my string
                selectedEvent.eventID = listOfEvents[indexPath.row].eventID
                print(selectedEvent.eventID) //print nil
     }
```

what am I doing wrong???
thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your code into a Playground you will get:

An error at the line

```
selectedEvent.eventID = listOfEvents[indexPath.row].eventID
```

Because your variable selectedEvent is nill since you've declared it but not initialized it. To do it, replace the line

```
var selectedEvent: Event?
```

with

```
var selectedEvent = Event(name: "YourEventName", eventID: listOfEvents[indexPath.row].eventID)
```

as Oleg mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at you're object `Event`. It is `nill`.

```
selectedEvent = Event(name: "Test", listOfEvents[indexPath.row].eventID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `listOfEvents` was an array of `Event` objects, you'd do:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedEvent = listOfEvents[indexPath.row]
}
```